# Runtime differences when evaluating constexpr function for different parameters

Tags: c++, optimization, constexpr

I wrote a simple recursive function, and added a constexpr flag to indicate the compiler that it can be calculated in compilation time.
When I call this function with two different parameters, I get different runtime results. why is that?

Code:

```
constexpr int plusOne(int i)
{
    return (i > 0) ? i + plusOne(i - 1) : 0;
}

#include <chrono>
int main() {

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    plusOne(200);
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ns\n";

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    plusOne(100);
    finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ns\n";

}
```

Output:

```
32472ns
3021ns
```

Comment: You aren't evaluating it in a context that *requires* it to be calculated at compile time (e.g. a template parameter, an array size, etc). So the compiler can choose what to do. You'd have to check the assembly to see what actually happens. What optimisation and debug flags are you using anyway?

Comment: I found the problem: the code was compiled in debug mode. when using Release, we do get similar results. Thanks @BoBTFish and S.M.

Answer (score 1):

Since results of `plusOne` calls are not used those calls are completely discarded and your example program essentially measures difference between first and subsequent calls to `high_resolution_clock::now`. You can [swap arguments and get similar results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VJgIK95Zoz6A0iQ3)